# ¿Porqué este código no imprime 5 caracteres?

Tags: javascript, web

me gustaría saber porqué este código javascript no imprime 5 caracteres si el array y el for son de 5.

```js
 var matriz=[
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
 ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
 ];
 var resultado=new Array(5);
 for(var i=0; i<5/*o resultado.length*/; i++){
  resultado[i]=matriz[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)][Math.floor(Math.random()*26)];
 }
 alert(resultado.join(""));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la longitud del array del que tomas el valor no siempre es 26.

El código elige aleatoriamente entre el array de números o letras, y toma un valor al azar entre 0 y 25. El problema es que aunque el array de letras sí tiene 26 valores diferentes, el de números sólo tiene 10. ¿Qué pasa si intentas acceder al valor 15 de un array de 10? Ahí está el error.

Una posible solución podría ser guardar el array aleatorio (números o letras) en una array temporal y elegir el número aleatorio basándose en el tamaño de ese array temporal y así las cadenas resultantes siempre serán de 5:

```js
var matriz = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
];
var resultado = new Array(5);
for (var i = 0; i < 5 /*o resultado.length*/ ; i++) {
  var temporal = matriz[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  resultado[i] = temporal[Math.floor(Math.random() * temporal.length)];
}
alert(resultado.join(""));
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que buscaba, no me había dado cuenta del error del array.